# Meaning of the word "repatriated" in this model

Tags: taxation

[image]

Hi, I am writing a thesis on transfer pricing and I am trying to figure out the meaning of what is written in this image. Company 1 is exporting some of its production to its affiliate company 2. So what does repatriated in this case mean? Is it what fraction of company 2's production that ends up at company 1 or is the effective tax what it saves or what is it? English is not my first language, so I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 4):

> repatriate 
> /riːˈpatrɪeɪt,riːˈpeɪeɪt/
>
> verb 
> send (someone [or something]) back to their own country.

---

> Is it what fraction of company 2's production that ends up at company 1

I would say profits instead of production, but otherwise yes.

---

**Example** (all numbers are made up)

Say Microsoft (MS) has to pay 20% tax in the US and 10% in Ireland. MS Ireland makes \$1 billion in pofits and transfers 40% of this back to the US parent company. In this case $f = 40\%$, and MS payed
$$
60\% \cdot 10\% + 40\% \cdot 20\% = 14\%
$$
of its Irish profits in taxes in *some* country, this is the effective rate at which it was taxed.